# I am trying to understand given log generated by Spark Program

Tags: apache-spark, rdd

I am trying to understand the log output generated by given simple program. Need help to understand each steps or reference to such writeup would be fine.

**Command** 
 sc.parallelize(Array(("a", 1), ("b", 1), ("a", 1), ("a", 1), ("b", 1), ("b", 1), ("b", 1), ("b", 1)), 3).map(a=> a).reduceByKey(_ + _ ).collect()

**Output :**

```
16/12/08 23:41:57 INFO spark.SparkContext: Starting job: collect at <console>:28
16/12/08 23:41:57 INFO scheduler.DAGScheduler: Registering RDD 1 (map at <console>:28)
16/12/08 23:41:57 INFO scheduler.DAGScheduler: Got job 0 (collect at <console>:28) with 3 output partitions
16/12/08 23:41:57 INFO scheduler.DAGScheduler: Final stage: ResultStage 1 (collect at <console>:28)
16/12/08 23:41:57 INFO scheduler.DAGScheduler: Parents of final stage: List(ShuffleMapStage 0)
16/12/08 23:41:57 INFO scheduler.DAGScheduler: Missing parents: List(ShuffleMapStage 0)
16/12/08 23:41:57 INFO scheduler.DAGScheduler: Submitting ShuffleMapStage 0 (MapPartitionsRDD[1] at map at <console>:28), which has no missing parents
16/12/08 23:41:57 INFO storage.MemoryStore: Block broadcast_0 stored as values in memory (estimated size 2.6 KB, free 2.6 KB)
16/12/08 23:41:57 INFO storage.MemoryStore: Block broadcast_0_piece0 stored as bytes in memory (estimated size 1588.0 B, free 4.2 KB)
16/12/08 23:41:57 INFO storage.BlockManagerInfo: Added broadcast_0_piece0 in memory on 172.17.0.6:31122 (size: 1588.0 B, free: 511.5 MB)
16/12/08 23:41:57 INFO spark.SparkContext: Created broadcast 0 from broadcast at DAGScheduler.scala:1006
16/12/08 23:41:57 INFO scheduler.DAGScheduler: Submitting 3 missing tasks from ShuffleMapStage 0 (MapPartitionsRDD[1] at map at <console>:28)
16/12/08 23:41:57 INFO cluster.YarnScheduler: Adding task set 0.0 with 3 tasks
16/12/08 23:41:57 INFO scheduler.TaskSetManager: Starting task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0, 34b943b3f6ea, partition 0,PROCESS_LOCAL, 2183 bytes)
16/12/08 23:41:57 INFO scheduler.TaskSetManager: Starting task 1.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 1, 34b943b3f6ea, partition 1,PROCESS_LOCAL, 2199 bytes)
16/12/08 23:41:57 INFO storage.BlockManagerInfo: Added broadcast_0_piece0 in memory on 34b943b3f6ea:28772 (size: 1588.0 B, free: 511.5 MB)
16/12/08 23:41:57 INFO storage.BlockManagerInfo: Added broadcast_0_piece0 in memory on 34b943b3f6ea:39570 (size: 1588.0 B, free: 511.5 MB)
16/12/08 23:41:58 INFO scheduler.TaskSetManager: Starting task 2.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 2, 34b943b3f6ea, partition 2,PROCESS_LOCAL, 2200 bytes)
16/12/08 23:41:58 INFO scheduler.TaskSetManager: Finished task 1.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 1) in 740 ms on 34b943b3f6ea (1/3)
16/12/08 23:41:58 INFO scheduler.TaskSetManager: Finished task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0) in 778 ms on 34b943b3f6ea (2/3)
16/12/08 23:41:58 INFO scheduler.TaskSetManager: Finished task 2.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 2) in 66 ms on 34b943b3f6ea (3/3)
16/12/08 23:41:58 INFO scheduler.DAGScheduler: ShuffleMapStage 0 (map at <console>:28) finished in 0.792 s
16/12/08 23:41:58 INFO scheduler.DAGScheduler: looking for newly runnable stages
16/12/08 23:41:58 INFO scheduler.DAGScheduler: running: Set()
16/12/08 23:41:58 INFO scheduler.DAGScheduler: waiting: Set(ResultStage 1)
16/12/08 23:41:58 INFO scheduler.DAGScheduler: failed: Set()
16/12/08 23:41:58 INFO scheduler.DAGScheduler: Submitting ResultStage 1 (ShuffledRDD[2] at reduceByKey at <console>:28), which has no missing parents
16/12/08 23:41:58 INFO cluster.YarnScheduler: Removed TaskSet 0.0, whose tasks have all completed, from pool
16/12/08 23:41:58 INFO storage.MemoryStore: Block broadcast_1 stored as values in memory (estimated size 2.6 KB, free 6.7 KB)
16/12/08 23:41:58 INFO storage.MemoryStore: Block broadcast_1_piece0 stored as bytes in memory (estimated size 1589.0 B, free 8.3 KB)
16/12/08 23:41:58 INFO storage.BlockManagerInfo: Added broadcast_1_piece0 in memory on 172.17.0.6:31122 (size: 1589.0 B, free: 511.5 MB)
16/12/08 23:41:58 INFO spark.SparkContext: Created broadcast 1 from broadcast at DAGScheduler.scala:1006
16/12/08 23:41:58 INFO scheduler.DAGScheduler: Submitting 3 missing tasks from ResultStage 1 (ShuffledRDD[2] at reduceByKey at <console>:28)
16/12/08 23:41:58 INFO cluster.YarnScheduler: Adding task set 1.0 with 3 tasks
16/12/08 23:41:58 INFO scheduler.TaskSetManager: Starting task 1.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 3, 34b943b3f6ea, partition 1,NODE_LOCAL, 1894 bytes)
16/12/08 23:41:58 INFO scheduler.TaskSetManager: Starting task 2.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 4, 34b943b3f6ea, partition 2,NODE_LOCAL, 1894 bytes)
16/12/08 23:41:58 INFO storage.BlockManagerInfo: Added broadcast_1_piece0 in memory on 34b943b3f6ea:39570 (size: 1589.0 B, free: 511.5 MB)
16/12/08 23:41:58 INFO storage.BlockManagerInfo: Added broadcast_1_piece0 in memory on 34b943b3f6ea:28772 (size: 1589.0 B, free: 511.5 MB)
16/12/08 23:41:58 INFO spark.MapOutputTrackerMasterEndpoint: Asked to send map output locations for shuffle 0 to 34b943b3f6ea:60986
16/12/08 23:41:58 INFO spark.MapOutputTrackerMaster: Size of output statuses for shuffle 0 is 163 bytes
16/12/08 23:41:58 INFO spark.MapOutputTrackerMasterEndpoint: Asked to send map output locations for shuffle 0 to 34b943b3f6ea:60984
16/12/08 23:41:58 INFO scheduler.TaskSetManager: Starting task 0.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 5, 34b943b3f6ea, partition 0,PROCESS_LOCAL, 1894 bytes)
16/12/08 23:41:58 INFO scheduler.TaskSetManager: Finished task 2.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 4) in 331 ms on 34b943b3f6ea (1/3)
16/12/08 23:41:58 INFO scheduler.TaskSetManager: Finished task 1.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 3) in 351 ms on 34b943b3f6ea (2/3)
16/12/08 23:41:58 INFO scheduler.TaskSetManager: Finished task 0.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 5) in 29 ms on 34b943b3f6ea (3/3)
16/12/08 23:41:58 INFO scheduler.DAGScheduler: ResultStage 1 (collect at <console>:28) finished in 0.359 s
16/12/08 23:41:58 INFO cluster.YarnScheduler: Removed TaskSet 1.0, whose tasks have all completed, from pool
16/12/08 23:41:58 INFO scheduler.DAGScheduler: Job 0 finished: collect at <console>:28, took 1.381102 s
res14: Array[(String, Int)] = Array((a,3), (b,5))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. As you can see, the processing started with collect() - This is the lazy initialization that spark uses. Even though you had map and reduceByKey, the process kicked off at collect. As map and reduceByKey are transformations
2. You can see 3 partitions and each having a task - since you initialized RDD with 3 partitions
3. Another point is how each of map and reduceByKey handled data locality. All three tasks in map have PROCESS_LOCAL. The
   reduceByKey needs a data shuffle and so you might have PROCESS_LOCAL and NODE_LOCAL.